# MPI_Type_vector with big dimension

Tags: mpi

I´m working with a dynamic matrix, and using MPI_Type_vector to pass each column to a process. i am defining the type like this

```
MPI_Type_vector(m,1,n,MPI_INT,&column_mpi_t);
MPI_Type_commit(&column_mpi_t);
```

m is the number of  rows and n the numbers of columns. This works fine when n and m are small, like 4 and 8 respectively. But when m and n are too big the program crashes with segmentation fault, saying m is 40 and n 80.

Someone know why this happens?? or using type_vector with size so big is not recommended?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where exactly does it crash when m=40 and n=80?

Comment: You will have to show much more code and try to generate a backtrace to identify the source line of the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fully agree with comments that you should post code.

In general, you probably did not allocate the right kind of buffer.  `MPI_Type_vector` is going to describe a region of memory.  This region is `MPI_Type_size` bytes, but it's going to be scattered over a range given by the lb and extent values of `MPI_Type_get_extent`.